# How to parse javascript array in php

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsing

One of queries on my webpage returned var that include data from link:

http://pastebin.com/a1XuhNpF

I think its a javascript array saved in mysql DB, but how to parse it in php controller ?

Comment: It's not a json array, it looks like serialized PHP. Look at [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize).

Comment: its is not a valid JavaScript array..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its serializa data , use `unserialize` http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php and you can use it

```
$_data = unserialize($your_data);
```